# How to merge children in multiple JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, merge

I have the following JavaScript object

```
[
  {
    "familyName": "Smith",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "John"       },
      {         "firstName": "Mike"       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "familyName": "Williams",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "Mark"       },
      {         "firstName": "Dave"       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "familyName": "Jones",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "Mary"       },
      {         "firstName": "Sue"        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I’d like to create an array of all children i.e.

```
[
  {     "FirstName": "John"   },
  {     "FirstName": "Mike"   },
  {     "FirstName": "Mark"   },
  {     "FirstName": "Dave"   },
  {     "FirstName": "Mary"   },
  {     "FirstName": "Sue"    }
]
```

I am using jQuery.

I have looked at posts that describe merging or concatenating arrays but not those of child arrays: e.g. [Merge/flatten an array of arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays-in-javascript)

I believe I could loop through the families and add the children arrays but suspect that there is a 'one-liner' for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tested in the console:

```
//The families(duh)
const families = [
{
    "familyName": "Smith",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "John"       },
      {         "firstName": "Mike"       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "familyName": "Williams",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "Mark"       },
      {         "firstName": "Dave"       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "familyName": "Jones",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "Mary"       },
      {         "firstName": "Sue"        }
    ]
  }
]
//Just flatten the children:
var children = [].concat.apply([], families.map(family => family.children));
//Outputs
console.log(children);
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution without jQuery would be to use `reduce` to extract children from their families (sounds a bit rough, sorry for that).

```
families.reduce(function(list, family){ 
    return list.concat(family.children);
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `$.map`:

```
var a =  [
  {
    "familyName": "Smith",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "John"       },
      {         "firstName": "Mike"       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "familyName": "Williams",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "Mark"       },
      {         "firstName": "Dave"       }
    ]
  },
  {
    "familyName": "Jones",
    "children": [
      {         "firstName": "Mary"       },
      {         "firstName": "Sue"        }
    ]
  }
]

console.log($.map(a, function(it){
    return it.children;
}));

// Or ES6
$.map(a, it => it.children);
```

Result:

```
[  
   {  
      "firstName":"John"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Mike"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Mark"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Dave"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Mary"
   },
   {  
      "firstName":"Sue"
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with `Array#forEach` method .then push the children object with new array

```js
var families = [ { "familyName": "Smith", "children": [ { "firstName": "John" }, { "firstName": "Mike" } ] }, { "familyName": "Williams", "children": [ { "firstName": "Mark" }, { "firstName": "Dave" } ] }, { "familyName": "Jones", "children": [ { "firstName": "Mary" }, { "firstName": "Sue" } ] } ]
var children = [];
families.forEach(family => family.children.forEach(child => children.push(child)));
console.log(children);
```